# How to load an item only once using an Android GridView adapter

Tags: android, gridview, android-adapter

I've got a custom `GridView` adapter (but that is irrelevant as I've seen this behaviour with other adapters too, but it's never bugged me this much), which I set to the `GridView` with a list of items.

My code in the function I call to create my UI in my `Activity`:

```
gridviewAdapter = new MyGridViewAdapter(this, itemList);
gv.setAdapter(gridviewAdapter);
```

My `getView` function in my adapter class:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        MyGridViewItemData itemData = itemList.get(position);

        Log.d(TAG, "MyGridViewAdapter-> Load view for " + itemData.getCategoryTitle());

        View v = new MyGridViewItemView(this.context, itemData );

        v.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) parent);

        v.setOnLongClickListener((View.OnLongClickListener) parent);
        v.setOnTouchListener ((View.OnTouchListener) parent);
        return v;
    }
```

From my logs I can see that the same item, in the list of items I give the adapter, is created multiple times; irregularly. I've seen the same item being created 18 times, and 48 times! This does not happen consecutively - the other items in the list are also created inbetween and also multiple times.

My logs:

```
MyGridViewAdapter-> Load view for Crops
MyGridViewAdapter-> Load view for Crops
MyGridViewAdapter-> Load view for Crops
MyGridViewAdapter-> Load view for Crops
MyGridViewAdapter-> Load view for Crops
MyGridViewAdapter-> Load view for Fruit
MyGridViewAdapter-> Load view for Crops
MyGridViewAdapter-> Load view for Crops
MyGridViewAdapter-> Load view for Crops
MyGridViewAdapter-> Load view for Crops
MyGridViewAdapter-> Load view for Crops
MyGridViewAdapter-> Load view for Crops
MyGridViewAdapter-> Load view for Crops
MyGridViewAdapter-> Load view for Fruit
MyGridViewAdapter-> Load view for Crops
MyGridViewAdapter-> Load view for Crops
MyGridViewAdapter-> Load view for Crops
MyGridViewAdapter-> Load view for Fruit
MyGridViewAdapter-> Load view for Crops
MyGridViewAdapter-> Load view for Crops
MyGridViewAdapter-> Load view for Crops
MyGridViewAdapter-> Load view for Fruit
MyGridViewAdapter-> Load view for Crops
MyGridViewAdapter-> Load view for Crops
MyGridViewAdapter-> Load view for Crops
MyGridViewAdapter-> Load view for Crops
MyGridViewAdapter-> Load view for Crops
MyGridViewAdapter-> Load view for Fruit
MyGridViewAdapter-> Load view for Crops
MyGridViewAdapter-> Load view for Crops
MyGridViewAdapter-> Load view for Crops
MyGridViewAdapter-> Load view for Crops
MyGridViewAdapter-> Load view for Crops
MyGridViewAdapter-> Load view for Fruit
MyGridViewAdapter-> Load view for Crops
MyGridViewAdapter-> Load view for Crops
MyGridViewAdapter-> Load view for Crops
MyGridViewAdapter-> Load view for Crops
MyGridViewAdapter-> Load view for Crops
MyGridViewAdapter-> Load view for Crops
MyGridViewAdapter-> Load view for Crops
MyGridViewAdapter-> Load view for Fruit
MyGridViewAdapter-> Load view for Crops
MyGridViewAdapter-> Load view for Crops
MyGridViewAdapter-> Load view for Crops
MyGridViewAdapter-> Load view for Crops
MyGridViewAdapter-> Load view for Crops
MyGridViewAdapter-> Load view for Crops
MyGridViewAdapter-> Load view for Crops
MyGridViewAdapter-> Load view for Fruit
MyGridViewAdapter-> Load view for Crops
MyGridViewAdapter-> Load view for Crops
MyGridViewAdapter-> Load view for Crops
MyGridViewAdapter-> Load view for Crops
```

**Why is this? And how can I get the adapter to only create the item if it's not being displayed yet?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
View v;

if(convertView == null){

    MyGridViewItemData itemData = itemList.get(position);

    Log.d(TAG, "MyGridViewAdapter-> Load view for " + itemData.getCategoryTitle());

    v = new MyGridViewItemView(this.context, itemData );

    convertView.setTag(v);

} else{

    v = (View) convertView.getTag();

}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Holder pattern in your case.

> If Android determines that a row is not visible anymore, it allows the
>   getView() of the adapter method to reuse the associated view via the
>   convertView parameter.
>
> The adapter can assign new data to the views contained in the view
>   hierarchy of the convertView. This avoids inflating an XML file and
>   creating new Java objects.
>
> In case Android cannot reuse a row, the Android system passes null to
>   the convertView parameter. Therefore the adapter implementation needs
>   to check for this.

Refer to this [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterperformance) for more details

Comment: I'm not using an XML file to display the view items. I create them in a custom MyGridViewItemView class. So how should I use the Holder pattern then?

Comment: MyGridViewAdaptaer extends ArrayAdapter<YourObject> then define your GridView in your xml file

Comment: I'm not using an XML file. I'm creating the layout programmatically.